# How do I create a Build Phase script to set CFBundleVersion to SVN Revision number?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, bash

I've seen some other questions on here that touch upon creating bash scripts to update version and build numbers in Xcode, but I haven't been able to find one that successfully updates the CFBundleVersion to the SVN revision number each time I do a build.

Does anyone have a script that I might be able to use?

Comment: This is what I am using for git. Maybe you can adapt it by replacing `git describe` with something similar for SVN. https://www.sourcedrop.net/Zi36be00350fb - You need to enable InfoPlist preprocessing from header file in build settings too and set CFBundleVersion to $GIT_VERSION in your Info.plist

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately I don't know enough about scripting to know how I would be able to amend that...

Answer (score 0):

I did this
[image]

in order to update the svn revision number. The script will be run each time you build the app. The string will be trimmed and only leave the current svn revision number, e.g. 4546.

Hope it helps!

PS: Here is the code so you do not need to rewrite it from the image.

```
echo -n ${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH} \
| xargs -0 /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion `svnversion | cut -f 2 -d : | grep -o \"[0-9]*\"`"
```